# VW 1978 beetle not starting - possible distributor issue

Tags: vw, beetle, distributor

A few days ago my car could not start, about an hour later it work perfectly.
Our neighbour who own one himself took a look and said that I need to change the distribution cap and rotor which I did.
The car won’t start, I have had the battery tested and go a replacement.
I followed the image [image: here] for the firing order. I have tried everything to get it working but it just won’t start.
Anyone with ideas on what I could do ?
It’s 1300 VW 1978 beetle.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have it correct? check https://www.thesamba.com/vw/forum/viewtopic.php?t=712764

Comment: @SolarMike i have it in the order of the picture, it would start for maybe a minute then die.
other orders cause backfires

Comment: You may have a fuel supply problem. I believe this is carberated. If it is, with engine not cranking, look down the carb while pumping gas pedal or throttle linkage. You should see spirts of fuel shooting in carb when pumped. If you don't, check fuel supply. If fuel supply is good, your carb needs work.

Comment: I wonder if the problem preventing the car from starting was not related to the distributor cap and rotor arm and has continued to persist.  Are you confident that the neighbour took sufficient diagnosis steps?

Answer (score 1):

Normal practice is to replace points, "condenser", rotor and wire , cap is secondary. I used to replace these parts about every 25,000 miles when I had them. That is, you have not replaced 3 of the most important ignition items. I had a 70's VW that would not start when cold because the enrichment or choke injector failed.

Comment: Will try it this evening and let you know\

Comment: I figured out the issue, the new rotor i bought was faulty and did not work correctly after switching the old one back it work,